# What effect does improving staff stats have?

Tags: game-dev-tycoon

I have played about 15 hours of Game Dev Tycoon and haven't really paid attention to training my staff. What I'm curious about is how much exactly does 1+ speed or 1+ research actually do, and is it worth training staff when I can just keep hiring new staff?

Comment: Pretty sure it makes them all generate more tech and design points for contracts and games faster. This allows you to finish bigger contracts and keep making your tech/design scores higher for newer games. At first hiring more staff is better since even level 2 employees have ~300 in one or both skills. Training an older employee for +300 would take forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[First part](http://gamedevtycoon.wikia.com/wiki/Staff)**:
The higher the number in research, the higher the amount of research bubbles (i.e. helps you to have more research points, which helps you to research/train more).

The higher the speed of a developer, the
Speed increases ratio of bubbles that are produced.

**Second Part**:
It depends. In the beginning hiring new staff is more efficient, as you will get better results and don't have to invest a lot of research points for training.
But at some point you have to start your own training to specialize your staff. Starting there, you have to continue training on your own to achieve better results.

Answer (score 0):

I started training my staff once I had 2 new employee's. It doesn't take an age to increase their focus to 300. maybe 3-4 training sessions. Its worth it.